# Can I Create A Windows Package to Submit to the Window Store using the Mac Version of Unity 5.3?

Tags: unity, windows, macos, appstore

Note: New to App Development.

I'm using a Mac for building my three 3D puzzle apps with Unity 5.3.2. I want to create Windows versions to sell in the Windows Store. I attempted to transfer the package for one of our apps to the Windows version of Unity but it was a pure hot mess. A lot of the alignment of text and images was skewed really bad. We have not used Windows in approx. 10 years so for all practical purposes we are brand new Windows users. The last OS we used was XP. The laptop we just purchased runs Windows 10 Home.

I can create a Windows executable (.exe) file from the Mac version of Unity that executes my 3D puzzle app perfectly just like the Mac version. However I found out that I had to submit a special package to the Windows Store. The instructions that I found so far for this assumes that you are using the Windows version of Unity.

I do not plan to be a full time app developer so the idea of trying to learn Visual Studio for me is a waste of my time. I would prefer creating the Windows package for the Windows Store using the Mac version of Unity. Is this possible? I could not find instructions in the manual or from search on what options need to be set to do this. I'm thinking it can be done since I was able to create a Windows exe file using my Mac version of Unity. I would like to create Windows Store packages for both 8.1 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a .exe to a .appx or related file to submit it to the Windows Store. [There is an app called *MakeAppx*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446767(v=vs.85).aspx) that came with Visual Studio for Windows 8, the Windows SDK for Windows 8 and 8.1 and built-in to Windows 10 that does it, but it can't be downloaded.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the uncertainty. I was pretty certain... I didn't mean to make it come across that way. :( | I'll try to improve the way I answer questions in the future!

Comment: I just checked my question again. I'm working on other Unity apps and plan to submit them to the Windows Store in a little while. Glad to see this update!